# Scopes chaining by OR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

How can I DRY these scopes?

```
  scope :reputed, -> {
    joins{reputations.outer}.
    where{['coalesce(rs_reputations.value, 0) > ? OR purchases.force_active = ?', LOWEST_VOTE, true]}
  }

  scope :reputed_or_mine, ->(user) {
    joins{reputations.outer}.
    where{['coalesce(rs_reputations.value, 0) > ? OR purchases.force_active = ? OR purchases.user_id = ?', LOWEST_VOTE, true, user.id]}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'coalesce(rs_reputations.value, 0) > ? OR purchases.force_active = true OR (? AND purchases.user_id = ?)',
LOWEST_VOTE,
!user.id.nil?,
(if user.id.nil? then -1 else user.id end)
```

This is semantically equivalent to both, but the AND in the third clause prevents it from having an effect when there is no user.id.

Comment: No thanks. It's looks uglier and contains errors.

Comment: @ck3g, can you be more specific about the errors?

Comment: Sure. `user.id` will throw error `Undefined method id for NilClass` or `called id for nil...` if user will not passed. Your solution is based on this.

Comment: @ck3g, Understood.  In that case, I'd declare the `user` argument with a default value that has an id of `nil`.

Comment: with OR in there, you don't get much other options. I don't support collecting in several steps and merging afterwards, because that's what a relational database is usually the best at. So I'm upvoting this solution.